# Not able to access columns for SqlAlchemy Relationships

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two table models

```
Class A(Base):
  __tablename__ = _a
  id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('C.id', ondelete="cascade"), primary_key =True)
  name = Column(Text, unique = True)
  b_relation = relationship(B, primaryjoin="foreign(A.id) == b.id"

class B(Base):
  __tablename__ = _b
  id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('C.id', ondelete="cascade"), primary_key =True)
  value = Column(Text, unique = True)
```

Class B can have multiple entries for one entry in Class A (one to many relation). Now when I try to access 'b_relation' property of tabel A, I get an error saying no such column exists.

The query i'm using to access the table is:

```
self.session.query(_a).all()
```

My basic requirement is to get data in a nested object format from both the table, something like:

```
{
  id: 123,
  name: "James Bond"
  b_relation: [
     {
       id: 000,
       value: "California"
     },
     {
       id: 007,
       value: "Mogadishu"
     }]
}
```

Comment: What is C and why are the `id` columns of both A and B declared as being foreign keys for it?

Comment: C is a table which has entries for all kinds of objects present. Let's say I has tables for car, chair and a phone. They are all objects and will have an entry in table C. They'll have a fixed unique ID associated with them in C and can be referenced anywhere based on that

Comment: Not sure either of these are the issue, but 1) you can use a string with the model class's name to get around instantiation order limits, and 2) you should be joining on the model name. So try `b_relation = relationship("B", primaryjoin="foreign(A.id) == B.id"`